# Javafx KeyEvent won't use Enter button

Tags: javafx, keyevent

I'm adding a onKeyTyped event to a textfield in javafx but the event keyCode won't equal the ENTER keyCode. I have tested that it registers the correct key typed.

```
public void button1Enter(KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
        button1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `code` for `KEY_TYPED` events is always `UNDEFINED`. The only way to get info about the key is stored inside the `character` property. (On windows it contains `"\r"` but on a different OS it may contain `"\n"`).

Alternatively you could want to use a `EventHandler` for the `onAction` event or use the `KEY_RELEASED` event.